# what user info do I need to send an email from his mail server

Tags: asp.net, email

I'm building an app where the user creates an email and where the email is sent from his mail server. I'm not looking to receive any emails, just to send them. I need to access his mail server to do this and I'm wondering a) what kind of email servers are there (Exchange, SMTP, POP3...) and what kind of info does the user need to provide me (ie. what fields do I need in the DB).

If you know of any pitfalls to avoid, please let me know.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP and POP3 are protocols, not Email Servers.

If I understand correctly, you need to connect to different email servers based upon the client that's constructing the email to send the email through his/her mail server(?)

If that's so, you need to, for every client of yours, find out their mail server's IP address and the type of authentication, encryption, etc. that they support. Once you have that established, you need to connect to each server based with the specific credentials provided by your client and send the email through their SMTP server. Example:

```
// Create a message and set up the recipients.
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
   "jane@contoso.com",
   "ben@contoso.com",
   "Quarterly data report.",
   "Hello, test email!.");


//Send the message.
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
// Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
            // YOU NEED TO CHANGE THIS PART DEPENDING ON THE SPECIFICS OF THE
            //SMTP SERVER THAT YOU WILL BE USING
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

try {
  client.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateMessageWithAttachment(): {0}", 
        ex.ToString() );              
}
```

Above example was taken almost verbatim, [from here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx)

Comment: I'm interested in what's needed to make the smtpclient object work for every possible user.

Comment: @frenchie that's too broad a question. Do you realize that you will be asking every user to provide username, password, encryption used, port numbers, etc. before they can send their emails? If you do, the sample code I've provided should be enough to get you started. The SmtpClient object has support for several auth mechanisms. Read the docs on MSDN.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking users for "all that"; what I'm wondering is what are the fields of "all that"? I plan to store that information and enable users of the application to send emails from their email server.

Comment: @frenchie ask them for: username, password,ip address of smtp server and whether it requires ssl (yes or not) & port number. That should cover most of your cases; if not all.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email is easy, how you store and manage this is up to you:

[Sending Email in ASP.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121616/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx)

**web.config:**

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network 
             host="relayServerHostname" 
             port="portNumber"
             userName="username"
             password="password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

**Code:**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); //used config settings
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I need a dynamic version: users will be sending emails from their server. These values cannot therefore be in the web.config file but instead must be determined at runtime based on the info provided by the user regarding their mail server